# Image upload PHP only work for some picture

Tags: php, image, upload

I'm trying to make a simple upload form to upload pictures to my local server,
it actually works, but the problem is that some pictures (type JPG) can't be read.
I don't know what the problem is.

code for handling form:

```
    <form id="addPTK" method="post" action="scripts/php/addPTK.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<table cellpadding="3px">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <div style="margin-bottom:10px;">
                <img id="noPic" src="images/contains/no-pic.jpg" style="width:148px;height:188px;border:2px solid #000" ><br>
                <input type="file" name="picPTK" style="width:55%" onchange="readURL(this)" />
                <script type="text/javascript">
                    function readURL(input) {
                        if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
                            var reader = new FileReader();
            
                            reader.onload = function (e) {
                                $('#noPic').attr('src', e.target.result);
                            }
            
                            reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
                        }
                    }
                </script>
            </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

and the code for processing in PHP:

```
<?php
    
    // Pic Var
        $nmFoto = $_FILES['picPTK']['name'];
        $tyFoto = $_FILES['picPTK']['type'];
        $szFoto = $_FILES['picPTK']['size'];
        $erFile = $_FILES['picPTK']['error'];
        $temp = $_FILES['picPTK']['tmp_name'];
        $tyFoto = $_FILES['picPTK']['type'];
        $dir = '../../images/ptk/';
        $ftExt = array('jpeg', 'jpg', 'png');
        $ftTemp = explode('.' , $nmFoto);
        $ext = end($ftTemp); 
?>
```

To check the data for the pic I am using this snippet

```
echo $tyFoto;
    echo $temp;
    echo $szFoto;
    var_dump($erFile);
```

on success it shows

```
Pic Name : 3dpencil10.jpg
Pic Type : image/jpeg
Pic Temp : C:\xampp\tmp\phpFBAD.tmp
Pic Size : 101632
Error file (var_dump) : int(0) << error shows (0) (i think it means (false)
```

for an unsuccessful image it shows

```
Pic Name : IMG_0668.JPG << It gets the name, but not the type
Pic Type : 
Pic Temp : 
Pic Size : 0
Error file (var_dump) : int(1) << error shows (1) (i think it means (true)
```

This is my whole upload script:

i know the name of POST file is different, one that i use above only for example.

```
<?php
/**
* ========= CREDIT GOES TO :==============
* Author : Ardian Septiadi AR a.k.a Refs
* Name : addPTK.php
* Version : V.01
* =======================================
*/
session_start();
if((isset($_SESSION['usercode'])) && (!empty($_SESSION['usercode']))){
    try{
        include_once dirname(__FILE__).DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'class.Table.php';
        include_once dirname(__FILE__).DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'fungsi.php';
        // Manipulasi SESSION
            $_SESSION['nik'] = trim($_POST['nik']);
            $_SESSION['namaPTK'] = trim($_POST['namaPTK']);
            $_SESSION['jkPTK'] = trim($_POST['jkPTK']);
            $_SESSION['unitPTK'] = trim($_POST['unitPTK']);
            $_SESSION['jabatan'] = trim($_POST['jabatan']);
            $_SESSION['alamatPTK'] = trim($_POST['alamatPTK']);
            $_SESSION['pdkTerakhir'] = trim($_POST['pdkTerakhir']);
            $_SESSION['gelar'] = trim($_POST['gelar']);
            $_SESSION['kawin'] = trim($_POST['kawin']);
            //Rubah Telp
            $telpPtk = noTelp(trim($_POST['telpPtk']));
            $_SESSION['telpPtk'] = $telpPtk;
            //Rubah Tgl Lahir
            $tglLahir = rubahTgl(trim($_POST['tglLahir']));
            $_SESSION['tglLahir'] = $tglLahir;
            //Username
            if(isset($_POST['hakAkses']) && $_POST['hakAkses'] == 1){
                $_SESSION['hakAkses'] = $_POST['hakAkses'];
            }
        // Batas
        // Untuk Data Pribadi
        $objAddPtk = new Table('PTK');  
        // Variabel Foto
            $nmFoto = strtolower($_FILES['fotoPTK']['name']);
            $tyFoto = $_FILES['fotoPTK']['type'];
            $szFoto = $_FILES['fotoPTK']['size'];
            $erFile = $_FILES['fotoPTK']['error'];
            $temp = $_FILES['fotoPTK']['tmp_name'];
            $tyFoto = $_FILES['fotoPTK']['type'];
            $dir = '../../images/ptk/';
            $ftExt = array('jpeg', 'jpg', 'png' , 'JPEG', 'JPG', 'PNG');
            $ftTemp = explode('.' , $nmFoto);
            $ext = end($ftTemp);
        // Proses Connect
        if ($objAddPtk->connect()) {
            if($nmFoto=='' 
                OR $_POST['nik']=='' 
                OR $_POST['namaPTK']=='' 
                OR $_POST['jkPTK']=='' 
                OR $_POST['unitPTK']==''  
                OR $_POST['jabatan']=='' 
                OR $_POST['tglLahir']==''
                OR $_POST['telpPtk']=='' 
                OR $_POST['alamatPTK']=='' 
                OR $_POST['pdkTerakhir']=='' 
                OR $_POST['gelar']=='' 
                OR $_POST['kawin']==''){
                    header('Location: ../../dashboard.php?panel=ptk&warn=1');
            }elseif(!preg_match("#[0-9]+#", $_POST['nik'])){
                header('Location: ../../dashboard.php?panel=ptk&warn=8');
            }elseif(!preg_match("#[0-9]+#", $_POST['telpPtk'])){
                header('Location: ../../dashboard.php?panel=ptk&warn=9');
            }else{
                // Upload Foto
                if((($tyFoto=='image/jpeg') 
                    || ($tyFoto=='image/jpg') 
                    || ($tyFoto=='image/pjpg') 
                    || ($tyFoto=='image/x-png') 
                    || ($tyFoto=='image/png')) 
                    && ($szFoto < 2000000) 
                    && in_array($ext, $ftExt))
                    {
                        // Set nama baru foto
                        $fileBaru = $_SESSION['namaPTK'].'-'.$_SESSION['nik'].'.'.$ext;
                        // Kondisi penyimpanan Data
                        if($erFile > 0){
                            header('Location: ../../dashboard.php?panel=ptk&warn=10');
                        }else{
                            if(file_exists($dir.$fileBaru)){
                                header('Location: ../../dashboard.php?panel=ptk&warn=11');
                            }elseif(isset($_SESSION['hakAkses']) && !empty($_SESSION['hakAkses'])){
                                // Manipulasi Username
                                $username = explode(' ', $_POST['namaPTK'], 3);
                                $rand = rand(1111, 9999);
                                $user = $username[0].$_POST['unitPTK'].$rand;
                                // Batas                                
                                $savePtk = $objAddPtk->save(array(
                                    'NIK' => $_SESSION['nik'],
                                    'PIC_PTK' => trim($fileBaru),
                                    'NM_PTK' => $_SESSION['namaPTK'],
                                    'JK_PTK' => $_SESSION['jkPTK'],
                                    'POSISI' => $_SESSION['unitPTK'],
                                    'JABATAN' => $_SESSION['jabatan'],
                                    'TGLLAHIR_PTK' => trim($_SESSION['tglLahir']),
                                    'NOTLP_PTK' => trim($_SESSION['telpPtk']),
                                    'ALAMAT_PTK' => trim($_SESSION['alamatPTK']),
                                    'STATUS_PTK' => $_SESSION['statusKaryawan'],
                                    'TMT' => $_SESSION['TMT'],
                                    'AKHIR_PROBATION' => $_SESSION['akhirProbation'],
                                    'STATUS_KAWIN' => $_SESSION['kawin'],
                                    'PDK_TERKAHIR' => $_SESSION['pdkTerakhir'],
                                    'GELAR_AKADEMIK' => $_SESSION['gelar'],
                                    'TGL_REGISTRASI' => date('Y-m-d'),
                                    'USERNAME' => trim($user),
                                    'PASSWORD' => md5(trim($user)),
                                    'LEVEL_AKSES' => 'Operator',
                                ));
                                move_uploaded_file($temp,$dir.$fileBaru);
                                // Manipulasi SESSION
                                $_SESSION['nik'] = '';
                                $_SESSION['namaPTK'] = '';
                                $_SESSION['jkPTK'] = '';
                                $_SESSION['unitPTK'] = '';
                                $_SESSION['jabatan'] = '';
                                $_SESSION['tglLahir'] = '';
                                $_SESSION['telpPtk'] = '';
                                $_SESSION['alamatPTK'] = '';
                                $_SESSION['statusKaryawan'] = '';
                                $_SESSION['TMT'] = '';
                                $_SESSION['akhirProbation'] = '';
                                $_SESSION['kawin'] = '';
                                $_SESSION['pdkTerakhir'] = '';
                                $_SESSION['gelar'] = '';
                                // Batas
                                header('Location: ../../save_success.php'); 
                            }else{
                                $savePtk = $objAddPtk->save(array(
                                    'NIK' => $_SESSION['nik'],
                                    'PIC_PTK' => trim($fileBaru),
                                    'NM_PTK' => $_SESSION['namaPTK'],
                                    'JK_PTK' => $_SESSION['jkPTK'],
                                    'POSISI' => $_SESSION['unitPTK'],
                                    'JABATAN' => $_SESSION['jabatan'],
                                    'TGLLAHIR_PTK' => trim($_SESSION['tglLahir']),
                                    'NOTLP_PTK' => trim($_SESSION['telpPtk']),
                                    'ALAMAT_PTK' => trim($_SESSION['alamatPTK']),
                                    'STATUS_PTK' => $_SESSION['statusKaryawan'],
                                    'TMT' => $_SESSION['TMT'],
                                    'AKHIR_PROBATION' => $_SESSION['akhirProbation'],
                                    'STATUS_KAWIN' => $_SESSION['kawin'],
                                    'PDK_TERKAHIR' => $_SESSION['pdkTerakhir'],
                                    'GELAR_AKADEMIK' => $_SESSION['gelar'],
                                    'TGL_REGISTRASI' => date('Y-m-d'),
                                ));
                                move_uploaded_file($temp,$dir.$fileBaru);
                                // Manipulasi SESSION
                                $_SESSION['nik'] = '';
                                $_SESSION['namaPTK'] = '';
                                $_SESSION['jkPTK'] = '';
                                $_SESSION['unitPTK'] = '';
                                $_SESSION['jabatan'] = '';
                                $_SESSION['tglLahir'] = '';
                                $_SESSION['telpPtk'] = '';
                                $_SESSION['alamatPTK'] = '';
                                $_SESSION['statusKaryawan'] = '';
                                $_SESSION['TMT'] = '';
                                $_SESSION['akhirProbation'] = '';
                                $_SESSION['kawin'] = '';
                                $_SESSION['pdkTerakhir'] = '';
                                $_SESSION['gelar'] = '';
                                // Batas
                                header('Location: ../../save_success.php');
                            }
                        }
                }else{
                    header('Location: ../../dashboard.php?panel=ptk&warn=12');  
                }
            }
        }
    }catch(Exception $e){
        echo 'Error: '.$e->getMessage();
    }
}else{
    header('Location: ../../index.php');    
}
```

i have tried to change it into STRTOLOWER, and also add several type in UPPERCASE, but still it doesn't work..

look for

```
if((($tyFoto=='image/jpeg') 
                        || ($tyFoto=='image/jpg') 
                        || ($tyFoto=='image/pjpg') 
                        || ($tyFoto=='image/x-png') 
                        || ($tyFoto=='image/png')) 
                        && ($szFoto < 2000000) 
                        && in_array($ext, $ftExt))
                        {
```

i use it to prevent user upload file but picture,
and i keep getting error because the type of picture assumed to unknown (not picture type)..
so i think it is the problem.

---

## Solved

LAST CHANGE i've made to my upload script which solve my problem, thanks for all:

```
<?php
/**
* ========= CREDIT GOES TO :==============
* Author : Ardian Septiadi AR a.k.a Refs
* Name : addPTK.php
* Version : V.01
* =======================================
*/
session_start();
if((isset($_SESSION['usercode'])) && (!empty($_SESSION['usercode']))){
    try{
        include_once dirname(__FILE__).DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'class.Table.php';
        include_once dirname(__FILE__).DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'fungsi.php';
        // Manipulasi SESSION
            $_SESSION['nik'] = trim($_POST['nik']);
            $_SESSION['namaPTK'] = trim($_POST['namaPTK']);
            $_SESSION['jkPTK'] = trim($_POST['jkPTK']);
            $_SESSION['unitPTK'] = trim($_POST['unitPTK']);
            $_SESSION['jabatan'] = trim($_POST['jabatan']);
            $_SESSION['alamatPTK'] = trim($_POST['alamatPTK']);
            $_SESSION['pdkTerakhir'] = trim($_POST['pdkTerakhir']);
            $_SESSION['gelar'] = trim($_POST['gelar']);
            $_SESSION['kawin'] = trim($_POST['kawin']);
            //Rubah Telp
            $telpPtk = noTelp(trim($_POST['telpPtk']));
            $_SESSION['telpPtk'] = $telpPtk;
            //Rubah Tgl Lahir
            $tglLahir = rubahTgl(trim($_POST['tglLahir']));
            $_SESSION['tglLahir'] = $tglLahir;
            //Username
            if(isset($_POST['hakAkses']) && $_POST['hakAkses'] == 1){
                $_SESSION['hakAkses'] = $_POST['hakAkses'];
            }
        // Batas
        // Untuk Data Pribadi
        $objAddPtk = new Table('PTK');  
        // Variabel Foto
            $nmFoto = $_FILES['fotoPTK']['name'];
            $tyFoto = $_FILES['fotoPTK']['type'];
            $szFoto = $_FILES['fotoPTK']['size'];
            $erFile = $_FILES['fotoPTK']['error'];
            $temp = $_FILES['fotoPTK']['tmp_name'];
            $tyFoto = $_FILES['fotoPTK']['type'];
            $dir = '../../images/ptk/';
            $ftExt = array('jpeg', 'jpg', 'png' , 'JPEG', 'JPG', 'PNG');
            $ftTemp = explode('.' , $nmFoto);
            $ext = end($ftTemp);
        // Proses Connect
        if ($objAddPtk->connect()) {
            if($nmFoto=='' 
                OR $_POST['nik']=='' 
                OR $_POST['namaPTK']=='' 
                OR $_POST['jkPTK']=='' 
                OR $_POST['unitPTK']==''  
                OR $_POST['jabatan']=='' 
                OR $_POST['tglLahir']==''
                OR $_POST['telpPtk']=='' 
                OR $_POST['alamatPTK']=='' 
                OR $_POST['pdkTerakhir']=='' 
                OR $_POST['gelar']=='' 
                OR $_POST['kawin']==''){
                    header('Location: ../../dashboard.php?panel=ptk&warn=1');
            }elseif(!preg_match("#[0-9]+#", $_POST['nik'])){
                header('Location: ../../dashboard.php?panel=ptk&warn=8');
            }elseif(!preg_match("#[0-9]+#", $_POST['telpPtk'])){
                header('Location: ../../dashboard.php?panel=ptk&warn=9');
            }else{
                // Upload Foto
                if((($tyFoto=='image/jpeg') 
                    || ($tyFoto=='image/jpg') 
                    || ($tyFoto=='image/pjpg') 
                    || ($tyFoto=='image/x-png') 
                    || ($tyFoto=='image/png')
                    || ($tyFoto=='IMAGE/JPG') 
                    || ($tyFoto=='IMAGE/PJPG') 
                    || ($tyFoto=='IMAGE/X-PNG') 
                    || ($tyFoto=='IMAGE/PNG')) 
                    && ($szFoto < 5000000) 
                    && in_array($ext, $ftExt))
                    {
                        // Set nama baru foto
                        $fileBaru = $_SESSION['namaPTK'].'-'.$_SESSION['nik'].'.'.$ext;
                        // Kondisi penyimpanan Data
                        if($erFile > 0){
                            header('Location: ../../dashboard.php?panel=ptk&warn=10');
                        }else{
                            if(file_exists($dir.$fileBaru)){
                                header('Location: ../../dashboard.php?panel=ptk&warn=11');
                            }elseif(isset($_SESSION['hakAkses']) && !empty($_SESSION['hakAkses'])){
                                // Manipulasi Username
                                $username = explode(' ', $_POST['namaPTK'], 3);
                                $rand = rand(1111, 9999);
                                $user = $username[0].$_POST['unitPTK'].$rand;
                                // Batas                                
                                $savePtk = $objAddPtk->save(array(
                                    'NIK' => $_SESSION['nik'],
                                    'PIC_PTK' => trim($fileBaru),
                                    'NM_PTK' => $_SESSION['namaPTK'],
                                    'JK_PTK' => $_SESSION['jkPTK'],
                                    'POSISI' => $_SESSION['unitPTK'],
                                    'JABATAN' => $_SESSION['jabatan'],
                                    'TGLLAHIR_PTK' => trim($_SESSION['tglLahir']),
                                    'NOTLP_PTK' => trim($_SESSION['telpPtk']),
                                    'ALAMAT_PTK' => trim($_SESSION['alamatPTK']),
                                    'STATUS_PTK' => $_SESSION['statusKaryawan'],
                                    'TMT' => $_SESSION['TMT'],
                                    'AKHIR_PROBATION' => $_SESSION['akhirProbation'],
                                    'STATUS_KAWIN' => $_SESSION['kawin'],
                                    'PDK_TERKAHIR' => $_SESSION['pdkTerakhir'],
                                    'GELAR_AKADEMIK' => $_SESSION['gelar'],
                                    'TGL_REGISTRASI' => date('Y-m-d'),
                                    'USERNAME' => trim($user),
                                    'PASSWORD' => md5(trim($user)),
                                    'LEVEL_AKSES' => 'Operator',
                                ));
                                move_uploaded_file($temp,$dir.$fileBaru);
                                // Manipulasi SESSION
                                $_SESSION['nik'] = '';
                                $_SESSION['namaPTK'] = '';
                                $_SESSION['jkPTK'] = '';
                                $_SESSION['unitPTK'] = '';
                                $_SESSION['jabatan'] = '';
                                $_SESSION['tglLahir'] = '';
                                $_SESSION['telpPtk'] = '';
                                $_SESSION['alamatPTK'] = '';
                                $_SESSION['statusKaryawan'] = '';
                                $_SESSION['TMT'] = '';
                                $_SESSION['akhirProbation'] = '';
                                $_SESSION['kawin'] = '';
                                $_SESSION['pdkTerakhir'] = '';
                                $_SESSION['gelar'] = '';
                                // Batas
                                header('Location: ../../save_success.php'); 
                            }else{
                                $savePtk = $objAddPtk->save(array(
                                    'NIK' => $_SESSION['nik'],
                                    'PIC_PTK' => trim($fileBaru),
                                    'NM_PTK' => $_SESSION['namaPTK'],
                                    'JK_PTK' => $_SESSION['jkPTK'],
                                    'POSISI' => $_SESSION['unitPTK'],
                                    'JABATAN' => $_SESSION['jabatan'],
                                    'TGLLAHIR_PTK' => trim($_SESSION['tglLahir']),
                                    'NOTLP_PTK' => trim($_SESSION['telpPtk']),
                                    'ALAMAT_PTK' => trim($_SESSION['alamatPTK']),
                                    'STATUS_PTK' => $_SESSION['statusKaryawan'],
                                    'TMT' => $_SESSION['TMT'],
                                    'AKHIR_PROBATION' => $_SESSION['akhirProbation'],
                                    'STATUS_KAWIN' => $_SESSION['kawin'],
                                    'PDK_TERKAHIR' => $_SESSION['pdkTerakhir'],
                                    'GELAR_AKADEMIK' => $_SESSION['gelar'],
                                    'TGL_REGISTRASI' => date('Y-m-d'),
                                ));
                                move_uploaded_file($temp,$dir.$fileBaru);
                                // Manipulasi SESSION
                                $_SESSION['nik'] = '';
                                $_SESSION['namaPTK'] = '';
                                $_SESSION['jkPTK'] = '';
                                $_SESSION['unitPTK'] = '';
                                $_SESSION['jabatan'] = '';
                                $_SESSION['tglLahir'] = '';
                                $_SESSION['telpPtk'] = '';
                                $_SESSION['alamatPTK'] = '';
                                $_SESSION['statusKaryawan'] = '';
                                $_SESSION['TMT'] = '';
                                $_SESSION['akhirProbation'] = '';
                                $_SESSION['kawin'] = '';
                                $_SESSION['pdkTerakhir'] = '';
                                $_SESSION['gelar'] = '';
                                // Batas
                                header('Location: ../../save_success.php');
                            }
                        }
                }else{
                    header('Location: ../../dashboard.php?panel=ptk&warn=12');  
                }
            }
        }
    }catch(Exception $e){
        echo 'Error: '.$e->getMessage();
    }
}else{
    header('Location: ../../index.php');    
}
```

LAST CHANGE i've made to my php.ini

; Maximum allowed size for uploaded files.
; http://php.net/upload-max-filesize
upload_max_filesize=10M

; Maximum size of POST data that PHP will accept.
; Its value may be 0 to disable the limit. It is ignored if POST data reading
; is disabled through enable_post_data_reading.
; http://php.net/post-max-size
post_max_size=10M

Comment: Are you setting `$_POST` values into you `$_SESSION` array only to clear them later anyway?

Comment: no i'm not, i do that because the process script is in different file, and when it shows the error the value of textbox or other will disappear, so a bit tricky i use session to keep it..it is just because i don't know how to keep it use the other way

Comment: You could save yourself a lot by simply doing `$_SESSION['post_data'] = $_POST`

Answer (score 0):

Unless you got other code

```
$ftExt = array('jpeg', 'jpg', 'png');
```

Remember that if no strtolower text....

.JPG is different from .jpg

You can use different ways like 1:

```
$ftExt = array('jpeg', 'jpg', 'png', 'JPG');
```

or strtolower the file name

Comment: hi Marco, thx to answering.

i tried both of the, but still it not shows the type

Comment: but the images are uploaded correctly? can you show us the upload code?

Comment: i already add the whole script i used, don't mind about file POST name, because the one i used before only for example

Comment: after Michael suggestion, check eventually if you got limitation on max_upload_size and how many file you can upload at once

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's because of the filesize?

You can try set following values in your `php.ini`

```
upload_max_filesize = 10M
post_max_size = 10M
```

Comment: i think the problem isn't caused by the size, because the error is "header('Location: ../../dashboard.php?panel=ptk&warn=12');", which mean the type of file isn't picture type

Answer (score 0):

Can you send usthe characteristics (filesize, filename) of an image that don't get uploaded ?

As others pointed, the verification of the extension may be the cause of your problem, that you can easily solve that way :

```
in_array(strtolower($ext), $ftExt)
```

But the filesize can also be an issue, as on most systems (so typical a shared hosting plan), there is a maximum filesize limit at 2M (which is why you often see websites restricting the size of images you can upload).

If I remember well, the $_FILES array contains an error index, so try to do a

```
print_r($_FILES)
```

And give us the result for an image that doesn't get uploaded.

Comment: Array ( [fotoPTK] => Array ( [name] => IMG_0668.JPG [type] => [tmp_name] => [error] => 1 [size] => 0 ) )

This is what i got when i print it

i also already set my php.ini like Michael said.

Comment: Well then, use this link http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.errors.php to match with the corresponding error (and print an appropriate message to your user if you can't fix the error). In your case, it is indeed a problem of file size.

Comment: So do you mean i need to change my php.ini ?
this is my php.ini

; Maximum allowed size for uploaded files.
; http://php.net/upload-max-filesize
upload_max_filesize=10M

; Maximum number of files that can be uploaded via a single request
max_file_uploads=20

and my picture file only about 3.5 MB..hmmmmm

Comment: On what kind of hosting plan are you ? Dedicated or shared ? If you are on a dedicated, changing the php.ini and restarting the apache service should be enough. On a shared plan, sometimes you simply can't modify the php.ini. You should check the FAQ of your hoster regarding that.

Comment: in the future ? this site will run only in intranet...i will try to restart my xampp first..